# Ruby on Rails 4 - Pass answer from one controller to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one newbie question.

Let's say I have two models ona called Project and the other one called Earning. Project has_many Earnings.

And in a view of 'Earnings' I have calculated the total of those Earnings. Is it possible to pass an answer from one Controller to another Controller to know what's the total of the earnings in a specific project. If so, how is that possible?

I don't know if the explanation is clear enough.

Comment: yes, you can copy the calculation action (where you you calculated your earnings) from your earningsController and paste it in your projectsController, then reference it inside any action in the new controller. Does that make sense?

Comment: Maybe the calculation logic should  reside in the Earning **model** and not controller.

Comment: It is a bad idea to call a controller from another controller.

Comment: Nebula, why? performing actions on a different model inside another controller is not recommended ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using data from the models to calculate `total`, then I would put that in the `Project` model instead of the controller. So you can calculate the total from the project's `earnings`. So you can call something like:

```
@project.total
```

Comment: Yes, you can call `@project.total` in any view. Just as long as `@project` is defined as a `Project` object and there is a `total` method inside of the `Project` model.

Comment: And let's say I have the result of the calculation in a view (i.e @ total = 10), can I assign that value in the current view to @ project.total using <% @ project.total = @ total %> and that will be save automatically in the database or should i do a differente procedure?

Comment: You should do the calculation _inside_ the `total` method. So if your project `has_many` earnings, then say something like `self.earnings.sum(&:value)` where `value` is the field in your database that contains the actual number of the earning.